# bookdown extensions in rmarkdown notebook

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr, bookdown

I would like to use some of the bookdown extensions while using `html_notebook` as my output format. E.g. this works:

````
---
output: bookdown::html_document2
---

```{theorem}
My proof here.
\```
````

```
knitr::knit("test.rmd", "test.html")
```

but this does not:

````
---
output: html_notebook
---

```{theorem}
My proof here.
\```
````

```
knitr::knit("test.rmd", "test.html")
```

Is there a way to use these extensions in rmarkdown notebooks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following output definition:

```
output:  
  bookdown::html_document2:
    base_format: rmarkdown::html_notebook
```

The manual for this feature can be found here: https://bookdown.org/yihui/bookdown/a-single-document.html

Comment: wow, this is fantastic.  I was actually looking for a specific behavior (fold/hide individual code chunks) that wouldn't work in Notebooks.  This looks like it may solve a great many such issues.  I might write a question with an answer that links to this unless you'd like to write this again.  I'm not worried about points and all that at this point :)